# Creating new DataFrame columns based on values in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been tearing my hair out trying to manipulate a pandas DataFrame. Hopefully someone can help me out!

I **have** a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Index Product ID Category Sale Amount
----- ------- -- -------- ---- ------
200   Prod1   01 Online   Yes  100
201   Prod1   01 Offline  Yes  150
202   Prod1   01 Online   No  123
203   Prod1   01 Offline  No   123
204   Prod1   02 Online   Yes  198
205   Prod1   02 Offline  Yes  175
206   Prod1   02 Online   No   148
207   Prod1   03 Online   No   193
208   Prod1   03 Offline  No   134
```

And what I **would like to create**, is a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Index Product ID Category Sale Amount Online-Sale Online-NoSale Offline-Sale Offline-NoSale
----- ------- -- -------- ---- ------ ----------- ------------- ------------ --------------
200   Prod1   01 Online   Yes  100    100         0             0            0
201   Prod1   01 Offline  Yes  150    0           0             150          0
202   Prod1   01 Online   No   123    0           123           0            0
203   Prod1   01 Offline  No   123    0           0             0            123
204   Prod1   02 Online   Yes  198    198         0             0            0
205   Prod1   02 Offline  Yes  175    0           0             175          0
206   Prod1   02 Online   No   148    0           148           0            0
207   Prod1   03 Online   No   193    0           193           0            0
208   Prod1   03 Offline  No   134    0           0             0            134
```

There are 4 extra columns in the DataFrame, each corresponding to one combination of (Category, Sale).

I eventually will slice this DataFrame further into this:

```
Index Product ID Online-Sale Online-NoSale Offline-Sale Offline-NoSale
----- ------- -- ----------- ------------- ------------ --------------
200   Prod1   01 100         0             0            0
201   Prod1   01 0           0             150          0
202   Prod1   01 0           123           0            0
203   Prod1   01 0           0             0            123
204   Prod1   02 198         0             0            0
205   Prod1   02 0           0             175          0
206   Prod1   02 0           148           0            0
207   Prod1   03 0           193           0            0
208   Prod1   03 0           0             0            134
```

Since the Sale and Category columns are redundant, I can get rid of them.

I've been hacking at this for the better part of today and I'm having no luck. I suspect I'm getting screwed up by the shallow vs. deep copying from different selection/slicing methods.

Thanks!

Comment: What will you be doing after you create this? My hunch is that you can achieve what you want using `groupby` rather than creating this (seemingly intermediate) frame.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'll edit my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood Phillip. This looks like an intermediate step where you wan't to calculate the offline/online sale aggregates, or something like that. If that is the case you should use groupby. If not, and this is exactly the thing you wan't you can accomplish it using:

```
online = df['Category'] == 'Online'
sale = df['Sale'] == 'Yes'

df['Online-Sale'] = df['Amount'][online & sale]
df['Online-NoSale'] = df['Amount'][online & (~sale)]
df['Offline-Sale'] = df['Amount'][(~online) & sale]
df['Offline-NoSale'] = df['Amount'][(~online) & (~sale)]
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df[['Index', 'Product', 'ID',
    'Online-Sale', 'Online-NoSale', 'Offline-Sale', 'Offline-NoSale']]


   Index Product  ID  Online-Sale  Online-NoSale  Offline-Sale  Offline-NoSale
0    200   Prod1   1          100              0             0               0
1    201   Prod1   1            0              0           150               0
2    202   Prod1   1            0            123             0               0
3    203   Prod1   1            0              0             0             123
4    204   Prod1   2          198              0             0               0
5    205   Prod1   2            0              0           175               0
6    206   Prod1   2            0            148             0               0
7    207   Prod1   3            0            193             0               0
8    208   Prod1   3            0              0             0             134
```

But this is pretty redundant, and, as @Phillip mentioned, if you want the aggregate values, you should use groupby.

Answer (score 0):

create a new key that is the combination of the fields you want to pivot.

```
df['key'] = df.Category +'-' + df.Sale
df2 = df.set_index(['Index', 'Product', 'ID', 'Category', 'Sale', 'key'])
df3 = df2.unstack().fillna(0).reset_index()
df3.columns = ['Index', 'Product', 'ID', 'Category', 'Sale', 'Offline-No', 'Offline-Yes',         'Online-No', 'Online-Yes']
```

reseting the columns is to remove compound index names

produces this result:  (remove extra columns if you want)

```
Index  Product  ID  Category  Sale  Offline-No  Offline-Yes  Online-No  Online-Yes
-----  -------  --  --------  ----  ----------  -----------  ---------  ----------
200    Prod1    1   Online    Yes      0           0           0        100
201    Prod1    1   Offline   Yes      0         150           0          0
202    Prod1    1   Online    No       0           0         123          0
203    Prod1    1   Offline   No     123           0           0          0
204    Prod1    2   Online    Yes      0           0           0        198
205    Prod1    2   Offline   Yes      0         175           0          0
206    Prod1    2   Online    No       0           0         148          0
207    Prod1    3   Online    No       0           0         193          0
208    Prod1    3   Offline   No     134           0           0          0
```